# itextpdf location TextRegionEventFilter returns letter by letter

Tags: java, itext

I have problem with itextpdf. I'm developing a resume parser based on LinkedIn generated pdfs.

Before I start to create location based filters I'd parse whole text with SimpleTextExtractionStrategy concat it as a one String and separate it by System.lineSeparator(). And I get a line after line in the same order like I have in pdf.

```
public String getNameAndSurname(PdfDocument pdfDoc) {
        SimpleTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        PdfCanvasProcessor proc = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);
        proc.processPageContent(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
        System.out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
        return strategy.getResultantText().split(System.lineSeparator())[0];
    }
```

But I need to read a line after line and separate Resume Blocks like Education, or Experience.

I have create custom filter extending TextRegionEventFilter. Everything's works, but in some cases I got value as single character. I have checked there is no special signs in splitted lines.

I have try to concat it but this is difficult to set rule when it should hapend.

```
 @Override
    public boolean accept(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (type.equals(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)) {
            TextRenderInfo renderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data;
                if (
                        setBlock(renderInfo, BLOCK_START, BLOCK_END) &&
                        isFontMatch(renderInfo, LINE_FONT_NAME, LINE_FONT_SIZE)
                ) {
                    super.elements.add(renderInfo.getText());
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Is it library bug? or how to even start to debug it?

I try to change a page size, from getFrom document to set it directly to PageSize.A4, I was also try to connect characters but I can't established when word is fully merged, because there is no rule when next world will be separated or not for characters.

output:

```
{
        "jobRole": "T",
        "company": "Company 4",
        "timePeriod": "XXX 2017 - XXX 2017 (3 months)"
    },
    {
        "jobRole": "r",
        "company": "Company 3",
        "timePeriod": "XXX 2016 - XXX 2016 (9 months)"
    },
    {
        "jobRole": "a",
        "company": "Company2",
        "timePeriod": "XXX 2014 - XXX 2015 (10 months)"
    },
    {
        "jobRole": "i",
        "company": "Company1",
        "timePeriod": "XXX 2014 - XXX 2014 (7 months)"
    }
```

Comment: The event listener gets the characters as they are drawn. If a text line is drawn in the PDF using a single string argument of a text showing instruction, the event listener gets the whole line, too. If a text line is drawn using a separate string for each character, the event listener gets the line character by character. No bug, just the design of PDF.

Comment: Thanks, for an answer, I have tried different pdfs and that is the case. In different pdf's it work fine. I have check now how SimpleTextExtractionStrategy implements ITextExtractionStrategy. My filters uses TextRegionEventFilter. Thanks for a track :)